Error: expected undefined to not equal undefined
I am trying to create a rating system.
My lib code is:
pub fn set_rating(ctx: Context<SetRating>, acc_address: String, rating: f32) -> Result<()> {
        let rating_account = &mut ctx.accounts.rating_account;

        // Check if the address already exists and update the rating if it does
        for entry in &mut rating_account.ratings {
            if entry.acc_address == acc_address.clone() {
                entry.rating = rating; // Update the existing rating
                return Ok(());
            }
        }

        // If the address doesn't exist, add a new rating
        rating_account.ratings.push(Rating {
            acc_address: acc_address.clone(),
            rating,
        });
        msg!("Set rating for {}: {}", acc_address.clone(), rating);
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn get_rating(ctx: Context<GetRating>, acc_address: String) -> Result<f32> {
        let rating_account = &ctx.accounts.rating_account;

        // Find and return the rating for the given acc_address
        for entry in &rating_account.ratings {
            if entry.acc_address == acc_address.clone() {
                return Ok(entry.rating);
            }
        }
        msg!("Getting rating for {}", acc_address.clone());
        Ok(0.0) // Return 0 if not found
    }

Also have a look at the structs:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetRating<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub rating_account: Account<'info, RatingAccount>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct GetRating<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub rating_account: Account<'info, RatingAccount>,
}

when I am trying to test in test.ts:
it("Sets and gets multiple ratings", async () => {
    // Set first rating
    await program.methods
      .setRating(accAddress1, rating1)
      .accounts({
        ratingAccount: ratingAccount.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc();

    // Get the first rating
    const ratingResult1: any = await program.methods
      .getRating(accAddress1)
      .accounts({
        ratingAccount: ratingAccount.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc();

    // Assert that the rating is correct
    assert.isDefined(
      ratingResult1.value,
      "Rating for acc_address_1 should not be undefined"
    );
    assert.equal(
      ratingResult1.value.toNumber(),
      rating1,
      "Rating for acc_address_1 should match"
    );

    // Set second rating
    await program.methods
      .setRating(accAddress2, rating2)
      .accounts({
        ratingAccount: ratingAccount.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc();

    // Get the second rating
    const ratingResult2: any = await program.methods
      .getRating(accAddress2)
      .accounts({
        ratingAccount: ratingAccount.publicKey,
      })
      .rpc();

    // Assert that the rating is correct
    assert.isDefined(
      ratingResult2.value,
      "Rating for acc_address_2 should not be undefined"
    );
    assert.equal(
      ratingResult2.value.toNumber(),


       rating2,
          "Rating for acc_address_2 should match"
        );

  });

I am getting error:
  AssertionError: Rating for desc_address_1 should not be undefined: expected undefined to not equal undefined


You didn't provide the RatingAccount struct, which based on your implementation it should look something similar to this:
pub struct RatingAccount {
    pub ratings: Vec<(String,f32)>,
}

Keep in mind that a vector stored in an account is limited by the initially allocated account size. While it's possible to resize the account with each new entry, doing so would add significant overhead to the program.
When using Anchor, you must allocate 8 bytes for the account discriminator. Additionally, the account will require space in the following format: 8 bytes + 4 bytes + ((4 bytes + length of string in bytes)->String + 4 bytes -> f32) * number of elements
Most likely there isn't enough allocated space for your account.
Suggestions:

Find a good model for generating derivation keys for PDAs and store each rating in a separate PDA.

pub struct Rating {
    pub acc_address: String,
    pub rating: f32,
}


Use u8 (1 byte) or u16 (2 bytes) if rating values are unsigned

values between 0.0 - 10.0 can be stored as u8
e.g 
f32: 5.4
u8: 54 

This can be displayed as (54/10) = 5.4

